# Fetch Conversions results of a campaign using SOAP API

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, fuel-sdk, node.js

In my app, I need to fetch results of an email send (campaign) and update it in our local database. I use following request to do so, which works fine and fetches the fields specified in the request:

```
{
      "RetrieveRequestMsg": {
        "$": {
          "xmlns": "http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI"
        },
        "RetrieveRequest": {
          "ObjectType": "Send",
          "Properties": [
            "ID",
            "Email.ID",
            "EmailName",
            "FromAddress",
            "FromName",
            "HardBounces",
            "InvalidAddresses",
            "NumberSent",
            "SendDate",
            "SendLimit",
            "Subject",
            "Status",
            "UniqueClicks",
            "UniqueOpens"
          ],
          "Filter": {
            "$": {
              "xsi:type": "SimpleFilterPart"
            },
            "Property": "ID",
            "SimpleOperator": "equals",
            "Value": "57XXX"
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Now, I also need to fetch conversions results for the campaigns. But I do not know what field names I should pass in the request to get the values of conversions. I tried using `UniqueConversions`, `Conversions` like given below but it gives error:

```
{
      "RetrieveRequestMsg": {
        "$": {
          "xmlns": "http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI"
        },
        "RetrieveRequest": {
          "ObjectType": "Send",
          "Properties": [
            "ID",
            "Email.ID",
            "EmailName",
            "FromAddress",
            "FromName",
            "HardBounces",
            "InvalidAddresses",
            "NumberSent",
            "SendDate",
            "SendLimit",
            "Subject",
            "Status",
            "UniqueClicks",
            "UniqueOpens",
            "UniqueConversions",
            "Conversions"
          ],
          "Filter": {
            "$": {
              "xsi:type": "SimpleFilterPart"
            },
            "Property": "ID",
            "SimpleOperator": "equals",
            "Value": "57XXX"
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

I am getting following error with this request:

> Error: Error: The Request Property(s) UniqueConversions,Conversions do >not match with the fields of Send retrieve.

Comment: A pointer is in your error message. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/send.htm you cant retreive conversion from the Send object.

Comment: Thanks @Data_Kid. Do you have any idea how I can retrieve conversions? Just give me some direction on it.

Answer (score 1):

If you check the documentation of Send:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/send.htm
The two properties you mentioned (UniqueConversions, Conversions) are not there.
That's why you are getting that error.